# Destroy object on Collision

Tags: unity, collision-detection, projectile-physics

I have a strange problem...  I need a 2D projectile to destroy itself after colliding with an object.  I have used all of the different ways to do this on the internet but to no avail; the object always collides with the way but is never destroyed!  This is my code:

```
public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision2D other)
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

The projectile is a prefab I made and it's attached to a controller I made for the main character.  The console is giving me the error, "This message parameter has to be of type: "  ... and I'm not sure what type is " ".

The projectile has a rigidBody2D attached to it and a circle collider.  The wall is an empty object with an edge collider.  I know that there is a collision because the projectile hits the wall and rolls down it.  However, my function "public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision2D other)" is never activated, and I don't know why.  I'm not sure what you mean by framework...  I'm totally new to unity and programming.

When the object hits the wall it simply rolls down it and lands on the ground.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want the 2D version of the method: [OnCollisionEnter2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnCollisionEnter2D.html)

Collisions with a Collider2D/Rigidbody2D won't send the "OnCollisionEnter" message, only "OnCollisionEnter**2D**"